# Problems linking with glut: "undefined reference to..."

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm attempting to get started using OpenGL, but cannot seem to link to some basic libraries correctly. Particularly I'll try to use some glut functions (like `glutInit`). Here's my code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize (250, 250); 
    glutCreateWindow ("hello");

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Here's what my make spits out:

```
g++  -Wl,--trace  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lXi -lXmu -o texture texture.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbegin.o
-lglut (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libglut.so)
-lGL (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libGL.so)
-lGLU (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libGLU.so)
-lXi (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libXi.so)
-lXmu (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libXmu.so)
/tmp/ccDzovHh.o
-lstdc++ (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libstdc++.so)
-lm (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libm.so)
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc_s.so)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc_s.so)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtend.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/tmp/ccDzovHh.o: In function `main':
texture.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `glutInit'
texture.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
texture.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
texture.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
texture.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
/usr/bin/ld: link errors found, deleting executable `texture'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [texture] Error 1
```

I've examined libglut.so with `nm -D --defined-only /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so`  and it appears to have the offending functions.

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

Also, I reinstalled glut (`apt-get install --reinstall freeglut3-dev`) and nothing changed.

Comment: Are you using freeglut? IIRC when I did a project with freeglut it was freeglut.h you had to include, not glut.

Comment: Just tried that and no change. Looking at what `dpkg -L freeglut3-dev` returns seems to indicate they are the same (it shows glut.h and freeglut.h but only a libglut.so).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Libraries need to be after sources. Try with:

```
g++ glutsample.cpp -o glutsample -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lXi -lXmu
```